# Horizontal floating div overlapping

Tags: css, html

I have designed a form with the following css **[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vQ78B/6/)**

```
.leftdiv
{
  float: left;
  width: 46%;
}
.rowdiv
{
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  clear: both;
  width: 80%;
}
    .rightdiv
    {
        float: left;
        width: 36%;
    }
```

When I am maximizing the screen the divs are overlapping as follows, so can some one help me how can I change the css so that is should display the same when maximizing or minizming the screen and textbox width should be same and label text can wrap...

[image]

Comment: Can we have some code please? So we can debug your issue

Comment: u should put some code.

Comment: you can check my jsfiddle

Comment: Try giving your input fields a smaller width..

Comment: Your demo is different and your screeshot is different

Answer (score 0):

Have you adjusted your css for your div tag class?

Example:
 Html:

```
<div class="textbox">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.textbox{
margin-right:5%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vQ78B/2/) Give width to your input:

```
input { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: Your demo is having 2 inputs and screenshot has 1. Try to demonstrate the same.

Answer (score 0):

i have a feeling that you are making a simple design complicated .. you are using too many `clear:both` , `float:left` . one of the reason for this problem can be the width allocation for each div , wrong calculation of width for your div hierarchy some times cause overlaping. and also your design and css in your jsfiddle very confusing and complicated.

i am giving you a new fiddle link. where i have created a design like you have. my div structure is

```
.container->.wrapper->rowdiv-> leftdiv & rightdiv
```

the key factors in my css to develop this design is `display: table` `display: table-row` `display: table-cell`

here `.wrapper`s  are table which can have many rows i.e `.rowdiv` and each row can have two cell those are `.leftdiv` & `.rightdiv`

there are three tables in your design which are one besides another thats why i used `float:left` in `.wrapper`

**[My FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6CRxP/2/)**

Comment: In our js, how to assign the margin-bottom: 4px for row div and when i am increasing the size entire  div is coming in below the first div,can you help this two things

Comment: (1) i am not efficient in jsp so i cant say (2) that will happen if summation of the width of your all wrappers becaome more than 100% then it will break the structure and  one will come below another one (3) wrapper of with must be 100 / (total no. wrapper) (4) see my edited fiddle you will understand

Comment: to solve those problem at run time using js you should start a new thread with jsp tag... your comment is out of the scope of this thread

Answer (score 0):

Instead of floating your elements try using display:inline-block or display: inline. That's a better way of handling your problem.